# DSolve problem with system of linear ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I encounter a rather strange problem in Mathematica when trying to solve the following system of linear differential equations:

```
M:={{0,1,0},{0,-1,1},{2,0,-4}}
ODESys := X'[t] == M.X[t]
InCond := X[0] == {5,0,5/2}
DSolve[{ODESys, InCond}, X[t], {t, 0, 1000}]
```

Despite the fact that the system should have an existing and unique solution (the eigenvalues of M are all nondegenerate and the eigenvectors are linearly independent), the ouput from the above code is empty, giving the warning

```
DSolve::bvnul: "For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary conditions lead to an empty solution".
```

However, there should not exist different branches. Also when using NDSolve instead of DSolve, the code works like a charm. Any ideas why the above code does not work for DSolve will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to define `X`: `X[t_] = {x[t], y[t], z[t]}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working. As in NDSolve there is no need to define the vector X explicitly (its dimensions are taken from the initial conditions), I assumed the same for DSolve, which was obviously wrong.

Comment: I have to admit that I find it an odd syntactical difference that `NDSolve` works while `DSolve` does not. I don't think I'd call it a bug, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 1}, {2, 0, -4}};
xm = {x[t], y[t], z[t]};
sol = First[
   DSolve[{D[xm, t] == mat.xm, (xm /. t -> 0) == {5, 0, 5/2}}, xm, 
    t]];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, 
 PlotLegends -> xm, Frame -> True]
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: Your code is clear. Thanks!